# Convert BMP to PCX C# Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, zebra-printers

Has anyone dealt with converting a BMP to PCX in the .net compact framework.

I need to convert a signature from a BMP to a PCX to be printed on a Zebra RW420 bluetooth printer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any code that does this for the CF, but the [PCX format is well documented and quite simple](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/graphics-pcx.html).  It should be fairly straightforward to create a converter.